# Django - Pysftp authentication error on template

Tags: python, django, sftp, pysftp

I'm trying to solve this but I have no clue how to.

I'm working with `pysftp` on Django. the problem is if everything goes ok, nothing happens but if I enter a wrong `host`, `usuario`, or `clave`. I'm still getting `Success` instead of `Error. Something Failed.` or `Authentication Failed` as say if I open Django console when I enter a bad `host` , `usuario` or `clave`. 
How can I make it work to get `Authentication failed` error in both places? Django console and Django webapp? 
**Thanks..!!**

Here's what I have:

```
def sftp_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sftpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            host = data['host']
            usuario = data['usuario']
            clave = data['clave']
            print host
            print usuario
            print clave
            try:
                SFTP_bajar(host,usuario,clave)
                messages.success(request,' Success')
                return redirect('auth_login')
            except:
                messages.error(request, 'Error. Something Failed.')
    else:
        form=sftpForm()
    return render(request, 'sftp.html', {'form':form})

def SFTP_bajar(host,usuario,clave):
    try:
        transferencia = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=usuario, password=clave)

        remotepath= 'myremotepath'
        localpath="mylocalpath"

        print ('\n' + 'Success')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't catch any exception in `SFTP_bajar`

```
def SFTP_bajar(host,usuario,clave):
    transferencia = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=usuario, password=clave)

    remotepath= 'myremotepath'
    localpath="mylocalpath"

    print ('\n' + 'Success')
    # here do whatever you have to do on your sftp server
```

Then in your sftp_form view change the way you are catching exception. One thing you must **never ever do is to catch broad exceptions like you are doing and ignore it**. Catch specific ones.

```
        from pysftp import AuthenticationException

        try:
            SFTP_bajar(host,usuario,clave)
            messages.success(request,' Success')
            return redirect('auth_login')
        except AuthenticationException:
            messages.error(request, 'Authentication failed')
        except :
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Thank you! but I'm having the following error in `exception`... `global name 'AuthenticationException' is not defined` .. how can I solve this?

Comment: You need to import it. I thought you had already imported relevent stuff from pysftp

Comment: That's it. Thank you sir!